How to solve pointer invalidation problem in GUI project?
I am creating small GUI lib, for buttons, checkboxes and etc and I currently use raw pointers to store Widget class objects in child list (Widget can be parent and also can be child too) like std::vector<Widget*> children. Lib runs internal loop where, for example, widget drawing takes place. If user will call delete on Widget object is will invalidate pointer to it. In destructor object can unregister itself from all parents, but cant remove it's pointer from internal lib buffer for drawing (if delete was called after draw function starts). How to guarantee what pointers in all internal buffers(including draw buffer) would be stay valid or at least null/empty checkable?

and I currently use raw pointers to store Widget class objects -- Well, I guess it's time to learn about smart pointers, probably std::shared_ptr. -- If user will call delete on Widget object -- It's time to rethink your design, where the user isn't given the ability to pull the rug out from under you without notification.  Why is the user getting access to the (raw) pointer, let alone be able to call delete on that pointer?

keep the objects by shared_ptr, use weak_ptr to break reference cycles formed by objects managed by shared_ptr

Why is delete invoked on a pointer to an object that is still in use? There's your bug. You need to properly manage the lifetime of objects. One simple way to fix that is the mentioned smart pointers, another is to use a garbage collector. Other methods specific to your application design may exist, too. I can't comment on that design since you don't provide any substantial info on it, maybe presenting it on codereview.stackexchange.com would be beneficial.

if delete was called after draw function starts i think every UI framework I've ever used only allows interaction with the UI from within the main ui thread for exactly this reason

One thing many gui frameworks have is weak references. It could be not threadsafe since only the UI thread should create or delete widgets, i have seen many ways to do it. In Qt and gtk every widget keeps track of weak references to it. But what i used before was a block that is allocated on the heap and all objects kept a weak_ptr to it except the widget, this saves space as all widgets tracking blocks have the same size and i can pool them

std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Widget>> Or if you need shared ownership : std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Widget>>. OR just rely on move semantics and use std::vector<Widget> which would transfer ownership to the vector, which may or may not be fine based on your design. Note the "design" part,  the lifecycle and ownership of your UI components must be designed up front (problems should not be corrected by tweaking your code after the fact)
